# Constrain fixed column width on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, so here's the situation:

- I'm experimenting with a fixed-width (resizeable) left sidebar
- The sidebar contains draggable elements
- If one of the elements is dragged to the right, then the sidebar column seems to be scrolling right.

Why is that happening? Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

---

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/t5nnmh94/

---

**Main HTML:**

```
<div id="main_wrap">
            <div id="sidebar" class="content-fluid">
                <span id="position"></span>
                <div id="dragbar"></div>
                <div id="components"><div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Components</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="one"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i><br/>E-mail</div></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="two"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-italic"></i><br/>Input</div></div>



                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="three"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-text-width"></i><br/>Textarea</div></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="four"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i><br/>File Upload</div></div>

                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="five"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i><br/>Password</div></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 component-item"><div class="wrp" id="six"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i><br/>Checkbox</div></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="content-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8" id="maina">
                <div class="panel panel-default" id="droppanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Main</div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="droppanelbody" >
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#ui-editor" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">UI Editor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#code" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-tab="code">Code</a></li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:40px;">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="ui-editor">
                                <form role="form" id="theform">

                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="code">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="thecode">

                                </textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4" id="options">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Options</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Panel content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Any chance of showing a jsfiddle.net demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker Just updated the original question! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have it - just do this:

```
#components{
    overflow: visible;
}

#draggableHelper{
    z-index: 100;
}

.panel{
 z-index: 99;
}

#sidebar{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

should work.

Comment: Another quick(?) one: Any idea why this one is not working? (http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html). It's the exact same thing conceptually (with a slightly better design). However, no matter how I played with `z-index`s and `overflow`s, I can't get it to work. (OK, if you have a look at the code, you might notice an... over-use of z-indexs lol, but I'm not such a guru with those things! lol)

Comment: Okay, create a new question for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429109/constraints-and-draggable-item-not-appearing-on-top-version-ii

Answer (score 1):

When you move an item in your panel's body, it changes the panel size to match all the content within.
This is the default behaviour.

You can try with :

```
overflow: hidden;
```

It will hide any visible overflow and keep the block size untouched.

Comment: Hmmm. JUST tried it. But here's what: as expected, the scrolling doesn't happen anymore. BUT: the draggable element disappears (since it's hidden in the... overflown section, I guess). Any ideas on that?

Comment: What scrolling are you talking about ?

Comment: The one that was happening. Well, in any case, your solution fixed that one. However, when dragging an element outside its container's limits, it now disappears. Any ideas?