# Constraints and draggable item not appearing on top - Version II

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

OK, so here's the situation:

I'm experimenting with a fixed-width (resizeable) left sidebar
The sidebar contains draggable elements
If one of the elements is dragged to the right, then the draggable element (the helper actually) seems to be disappearing behind the main content.

Why is that happening? Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

**Demo:** `http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html`

---

This one is almost an exact duplicate of a similar question I had posted earlier, although the solution to this one seems to me rather far from obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.slimScrollDiv **SET** overflow: visible;

.hbox, #content, .vbox **AND** following (if there are some) - **remove** z-index tag!

this was your mistake. Hope it works now, the adding on a Pane seem not to be implemented.

Comment: Hmm. Did this work for you? It doesn't seem to make any difference at all... (p.s. thanks a lot for your help, in any case! ;-) )

Comment: it fixed that the element is hidden after left the ScrollDiv - now im working on fixing the thing with the block-post DIV

Comment: Okay now try .form-group{ z-index: 99; } ;)

Comment: Aww :( okay here .vbox{ z-index:0; } :)

Comment: OK, sorry to disappoint you, but... (I'll say it... arghh) it still doesn *not* work. :( No matter what, I **really** appreciate all your efforts. And btw, are you really 16?! Keep it up, my friend! ;-)

Comment: Okay, I updated my post, follow the discription - I guess u broke something.. :/

Comment: Well, I'm about to... break my head against a wall. lol. It's one of those cases, where you end up doing whatever-you-come-up-with, simply to make it work! Pfff...

Comment: Could you please have a look at the code as it right now? (I'm confused as to what I added or not)

Comment: Everything nice but u have to change the <div class="slimScrollDiv" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; ....> to overflow:visible

Comment: Hmm.. There is no such `div` in the code. The only thing related to `slimScrollDiv` I can find is `.slimScrollDiv{ overflow: visible; }` which I added a few minutes ago.

Comment: Aha. Ok, I think I got it. It's being auto-generated. Give me a sec.

Comment: Okie dokie. So, have a look again : `http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html`. **Amazing**. It worked. You were 100% correct. OK, instead of just thanking you, given your impressive commitment, send me your e-mail. I think I'll have work for you in the future! ;-) Thanks again, buddy! :-)

Comment: Well, nice to hear :) looks good! If you take a look at my profile you should be able to see my E-Mail ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because the JavaScript is modifying it I can't know for sure. However, my initial thoughts are it has to do with the z-index. The z-index for the center section is 99, and the lis are 0-10. Try making it update the z-index of the lis to 100+ on move.

Answer (score 1):

I seems this remove position in left menu side and white drop box and set droppable menu z-index and position absolute may it works for you